# How can i remove a node from this list and then print it?

Tags: c, list

The main idea: make a list of food+calories, print it, ask for what entry to remove then print the list with that removed entry. Can't seem to make it work.

I originally only wanted to print the initial list, but then later on decided to also ask the user for a specific entry to be removed and the list printed again. This is where i failed to make it work.

The errors given by the compiler are:

> 1.[Error] 'struct info' has no member named 'current'(lines 91 and 99 in function deleteNode)
>   2.[Error] dereferencing pointer to incomplete type (in function printList)

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct info {
int calories;
char name[100];
struct info *next;
};

void add_info(struct info *s);
struct info *create(void);
void printList();
void deleteNode ();

int main()
{
struct info *first;
struct info *current;
struct info *new;      
int x, i, y;

printf("\t\tHow many entries do you want? ");
scanf("%d",&x);

first = create();
current = first;

for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    if(i==0)
    {

        first = create();
        current = first;
    }
    else
    {
        new = create();
        current->next = new;
        current = new;
    }
    add_info(current);
}
current->next = NULL;

current = first;       
while(current)
{
    printf("\n\nCalories per food:  %d\t Name of the food: %s\n",current->calories,current->name);
    current = current->next;
}
printf("Which entry would you like to remove? ");
scanf("%d", &y);
deleteNode(y);
printf("The list after deletion is: ");
printfList();

return(0);
}


void add_info(struct info *s)
{
printf("Insert number of calories: ");
scanf("%d",&s->calories);
printf("\n Insert name of the food: ");
scanf("%s",&s->name);
s->next = NULL;
}


struct info *create(void)
{
struct info *initial;

initial = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
if( initial == NULL)
{
    printf("Memory error");
    exit(1);
}
return(initial);
}

void deleteNode(struct info **s, int y)
{

struct info* temp = *s, *prev;


if (temp != NULL && temp->current == y)
{
    *s = temp->next;  
    free(temp);              
    return;
}


while (temp != NULL && temp->current != y)
{
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}


if (temp == NULL) return;


prev->next = temp->next;

free(temp);
}

void printList(struct list *info)
{
while (info != NULL)
{
    printf(" %d %s ", info->calories, info->name);
    info = info->next;
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, replace the manual input with hardcoded values and also remove other things that are not necessary. Also, where and how exactly does it fail?

Comment: That's a lot of code to search through.

Comment: Read the error messages carefully. What parts of them do you need help with understanding? Also, if you need more help, you need to clearly show us what lines cause the errors.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt my bad sorry, first time posting. i edited my op. basically the errors are in the later added functions: deleteNode and printList, namely the fact that 'struct info' has no member called 'current'. there's also errors in printList that i mentioned in the edit, but i don't really understand it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice hi there, i edited my post now and it includes the lines that give errors. i believe i have wrongfully declared and used parameters in those functions

Comment: @AndreiVicol `struct info` has no member named `current`. The error message is clear. The other error is a bit less obvious, it's because you don't provide the definition of `struct list`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and how do i go about fixing that 'current' error? that is the part that is least clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.[Error] 'struct info' has no member named 'current'(lines 91 and 99 in function deleteNode)

Look at this declaration:

```
struct info {
    int calories;
    char name[100];
    struct info *next;
};
```

Then you have a variable declaration like this:

```
struct info* temp = *s
```

And you try to use it like this:

```
temp->current
```

but there is no name `current` inside the `info` struct. There are three other names instead. You need to decide which of those is most appropriate for what you are trying to do.

> 2.[Error] dereferencing pointer to incomplete type (in function printList)

Look at this line of code:

```
void printList(struct list *info)
```

You have no declaration `struct list` and you are declaring a **variable** named `info` which is not the same as the `struct info` which you already declared. Instead you need something like this:

```
void printList(struct info* list)
```

This declares a parameter named `list` which is a pointer to a `struct info`. Now everywhere you have `info` inside this `printList()` function, you need to say `list` instead.

Comment: i want to remove both the name of the food and its corresponding calories, so i need to use both `calories` and `name`?

Comment: thank you, dont know how i mixed those up. will change it and come back with details

Comment: that fixed the issue with printList, and now am only left with errors in deleteNode, namely " 'struct info' has no member named 'current'(lines 91 and 99)"

Comment: @AndreiVicol Read the first part of my answer.